# Is it possible to write a rust macro that transposes a matrix?

Tags: matrix, rust, macros, transpose, rust-macros

I am currently working on [optimizing the rust jpeg decoder crate](https://github.com/image-rs/jpeg-decoder/pull/146) using SIMD. In order to avoid long repetitions in the code, I would like to write a macro that generates the following matrix transposition code :

```rust
s = [
        i32x8::new(s[0].extract(0),s[1].extract(0),s[2].extract(0),s[3].extract(0),s[4].extract(0),s[5].extract(0),s[6].extract(0),s[7].extract(0), ),
        i32x8::new(s[0].extract(1),s[1].extract(1),s[2].extract(1),s[3].extract(1),s[4].extract(1),s[5].extract(1),s[6].extract(1),s[7].extract(1), ),
        i32x8::new(s[0].extract(2),s[1].extract(2),s[2].extract(2),s[3].extract(2),s[4].extract(2),s[5].extract(2),s[6].extract(2),s[7].extract(2), ),
        i32x8::new(s[0].extract(3),s[1].extract(3),s[2].extract(3),s[3].extract(3),s[4].extract(3),s[5].extract(3),s[6].extract(3),s[7].extract(3), ),
        i32x8::new(s[0].extract(4),s[1].extract(4),s[2].extract(4),s[3].extract(4),s[4].extract(4),s[5].extract(4),s[6].extract(4),s[7].extract(4), ),
        i32x8::new(s[0].extract(5),s[1].extract(5),s[2].extract(5),s[3].extract(5),s[4].extract(5),s[5].extract(5),s[6].extract(5),s[7].extract(5), ),
        i32x8::new(s[0].extract(6),s[1].extract(6),s[2].extract(6),s[3].extract(6),s[4].extract(6),s[5].extract(6),s[6].extract(6),s[7].extract(6), ),
        i32x8::new(s[0].extract(7),s[1].extract(7),s[2].extract(7),s[3].extract(7),s[4].extract(7),s[5].extract(7),s[6].extract(7),s[7].extract(7), ),
];
```

The macro should be able to generate the code for different matrix sizes (4 or 8).

I have tried several different approaches, but I never manage to get the macro to repeat n times an n-item pattern.

The most logical to me would be:

```rust
macro_rules! square {
    (($($x:tt),*), ($($y:tt),*)) => {
        [
            $([ 
                $( s[$x].extract($y) ),* 
            ]),*
        ]
    };
    ($($x:expr),*) => { square!( ($($x),*) , ($($x),*) ) };
}
```

but it fails with

```
error: attempted to repeat an expression containing no syntax variables matched as repeating at this depth
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it, but you will need to handle the outer repetition through recursion:

```
macro_rules! square {
    (@row [$($acc:expr),*] [$($before:expr),*] $current:expr $(, $after:expr)*) => {
        square!(@row
            [ $($acc,)*
              stringify!($(s[$current].extract ($before),)*
                         s[$current].extract ($current)
                         $(, s[$current].extract ($after))*) ]
            [ $($before,)* $current ]
            $($after),*)
    };
    (@row [$($acc:tt)*] [$($before:expr),*]) => { vec![ $($acc)* ] };
    ($($r:expr),*) => {
        square!(@row [] [] $($r),*)
    };
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=544cf6b7272dcc12108f96f4235dfb29)

I've called `stringify!` so that the code would compile on the playground without the dependencies. You will need to replace them to fit your needs (probably just remove the `stringify!` invocation and replace `s` by an identifier you pass to the macro).

The idea of accumulating the values in `$acc` and outputting them all at once at the end of the recursion is called the [push-down accumulation pattern](https://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book/pat-push-down-accumulation.html). If you are not familiar with this concept, it is described in detail in the [little book of Rust macros](https://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book/).

Comment: Great, thank you ! The key element that I missed was keeping the history of the elements that were already seen (the $before) while recursing.